# Shotwell Viewer can't open files without file ending

Tags: shotwell, file-format, filename

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine.

When I try to open an image without file extension (e.g `.png`) using **Shotwell Viewer**, it shows the error:

> "Shotwell does not support the file format of `/home/[USER]/Pictures/testImage`."

How can I view images without file extension with shotwell?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `mimetype /home/[USER]/Pictures/testImage`

Comment: The output for the above command is: /home/[USER]/Pictures/testImage:image/png

Comment: Same problem here in Wily

Comment: Does it work if you rename the file?

Comment: Can you open open them with Eye of Gnome, i.e. by just double clicking on the file?

Comment: I've tested it. Works with suffix, but not without. Same for JPG. Write a bug report =)

Comment: Confirming same behaviour for shotwell version `0.22.0-0ubuntu5` on Ubuntu 15.10 (Wily). `eog` in contrast opens the file without extension as well.

Comment: Same here (Shotwell 0.22.0 / Ubuntu 15.10).

Answer (score 1):

> How can I view images without file extension with shotwell?

The answer is short:

You can't. It works with a suffix, but not without. The same for JPGs and so on. You have found a four years old bug.

Here is the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/shotwell/+bug/878472).